# Delay of a few seconds before display:none

Tags: javascript, timer

I don't know how to achieve that `display: none` works not immediately.
I need #popUpBox to disappear after a few seconds.

```
  $(document).bind("mousedown", function(){
        $('#popUpBox').css({'display':'none'});
```

---

```
jQuery(function($) {

var $txt = '';

$('.selectiontext').bind("mouseup", function(e){
    if (window.getSelection){
        $txt = window.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.getSelection){
        $txt = document.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.selection){
        $txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    else return;
    if    ($txt!=''){
        $('#popUpBox').css({'display':'block', 'left':e.pageX+5+'px', 'top':e.pageY+0+'px'});
    }
});

$(document).bind("mousedown", function(){
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#popUpBox').css({'display':'none'});
}, 2000);


});
```

Unfortunately, when i select text, now always #popUpBox disappears and i need only when selection is disabled

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the setTimeout function.

```
$(document).bind("mousedown", function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#popUpBox').css({'display':'none'});
    }, *time you want(int)*);
});
```

**Edit** : To your new question

Add a if statement when selection is disabled. Here :

```
$(document).bind("mousedown", function(){ 
    *if statement*
        setTimeout(function() { (...)
```

Because it's bound to the entire document, it will always hide the box without any condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want the function to trigger a few seconds after the `mousedown` event:

```
$(document).bind("mousedown", function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#popUpBox').css({'display':'none'});
    }, 5000);
});
```

Readup on setTimeout [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout). Basically, `setTimeout()` allows you to pass a function and then an interval (in milliseconds) to wait before executing that function.

Edit (for update): To only have this happen when there is no selection, try:

```
$(document).bind("mousedown", function(){
    if (!window.getSelection) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#popUpBox').css({'display':'none'});
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you could, up vote my answer for anyone else perusing the thread so they know it works :)

Comment: I added a bit of information, can you help? :-(

Comment: Edited, hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The following code will hide the div after 2 seconds

```
$("#popUpBox").delay(2000).hide();
```

If you want animation, you can use fadeOut method as well

```
$("#popUpBox").delay(2000).fadeOut('fast');
```